# CursorAdapter and OnItemClickListener for ListView Related Questions

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contentprovider, onitemclicklistener, android-cursor

I would like to two questions related to the behavior of `OnItemClickListener`, when using a cursor adapter for my listivew. More specifically:

I have overridden the `getCount()` of cursor adapter in order to add a log (in order to check when it is called). I have noticed that when I click on an item of the list, I see that the getCount() has been executed twice. I don't really understand why this is happening.. Below is the overridden `getCount()`. `mCursor` is a cursor object of my adapter.

```
   @Override
public int getCount() {
    if (mCursor != null) {
        int total = mCursor.getCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "Count of cursor is: " + total);
        return total;
    } else
        Log.e(TAG, "Count of cursor is: " + 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Secondly, from this listener I want to start another activity. When I click an item, I get the following exception:

> 08-26 14:15:20.487: DEBUG/AgendaAdapter(14110): Count of cursor is: 14
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.525: DEBUG/AgendaAdapter(14110): Count of cursor is: 14
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.535: DEBUG/AgendaActivity(14110): Position is: 2
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.535: DEBUG/AgendaActivity(14110): Id is: 353
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.535: INFO/ActivityManager(104): Starting activity: Intent {AgendaEventActivity (has extras) }
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.575: DEBUG/AgendaActivity(14110): onPause
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.865: INFO/ActivityManager(104): Displayed activity AgendaEventActivity: 287 ms (total 287 ms)
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.875: DEBUG/AgendaAdapter(14110): Count of cursor is: 14
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.875: DEBUG/AgendaAdapter(14110): Count of cursor is: 14
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.885: DEBUG/AgendaAdapter(14110): Count of cursor is: 14
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.885: DEBUG/AgendaAdapter(14110): Count of cursor is: 14
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.885: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(14110): Shutting down VM
>
> 08-26 14:15:20.885: WARN/dalvikvm(14110): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40028a00)
>   08-26 14:15:20.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14110): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-26 14:15:20.905: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(14110): java.lang.IllegalStateException: this should only be called when the cursor is valid

So, the `getCount()` is executed when I click an item, then follows two logs from `onItemClickListener` with the `pos` and the `id` of the clicked item, and then `getCount()` is called again... Finally the current activity get paused and the new one that I start get this `IllegalStateException`, which I cant understand why..

For the cursor, I used managedquery() when I start it..

Any help would be really grateful! Thank you for your time!

The stack trace of the exception is:

> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173): java.lang.IllegalStateException: this should only be called when the cursor is valid
>   08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.CursorAdapter.getView(CursorAdapter.java:175)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1272)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1591)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1049)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.735: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(24173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

And this is the dumpStack from getCount():

> 08-26 14:35:17.615: WARN/System.err(24173): java.lang.Throwable: stack dump
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.695: DEBUG/dalvikvm(24173): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 19264 objects / 1052704 bytes in 78ms
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.695: WARN/System.err(24173):     at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:618)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at AgendaAdapter.getCount(AgendaAdapter.java:31)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1491)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:909)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.705: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7034)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1049)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4914)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
>
> 08-26 14:35:17.715: WARN/System.err(24173):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Thus it is called from the `ListView`, but how can it be called after `onPause()` of the activity?

Comment: Finally, I found a solution (without exactly understanding why the previous approach wasn't working..). Instead of managedQuery(), I now use query() and close the cursor at onDestroy(). Thus, I suppose that the way managedQuery manages the lifecycle of the cursor is problematic (???) when activity pauses.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting a call to `Thread.dumpStack()` in your `getCount()` method to see what's calling it.

Can you post the stack trace from the IllegalStateException?